# Push notification Click event is not working when app is in Background in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using phonegap-plugin-push plugin for FCM push notification,

Here I am able to get notification when app is running in background or app is in active status notification is working fine in this state.

But when app is in background state and any notificaiton came in that condition if any user click on the notificaiotn he must be redirect on any spacific page, for this I try so many way but its not working .

I am using following code to initialize notification

var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: '436009364694',
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        icon: 'icon',
        sound: true,
        vibrate: true
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true",
        vibrate: true,
        clearBadge: true
    },
    windows: {}
});

And I am using following code to trigger the notification

push.on('notification', function(data) {
});

above code is only working when app is in running state but its not working when app is in background,

Any one know how to trigger click event if app in background state